# Gradient descent relaxation dynamics of a Euler-Lagrange equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, convex-optimization, calculus-of-variations, hamiltonian-mechanics, gradient-flows

I want to minimize the functional
$$
F=\int{L(u)}dx,
$$
where $L= u_x^2-u^2$ is the Lagrangian function of the functional. Even if its Euler-Lagrange equation is easily found and solved, I want to try another approach i.e. solve it as a gradient descent problem. I'd like to try this approach since, if I succeed, this would turn out to be a general approach, so I could try to use it  even when the Euler-Lagrange equations will be hard to solve due to the structure of the functional involved. I propose to solve it in the form of the following gradient descent dynamics problem:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=-\frac{\delta{L}}{\delta{u}}=2u+2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2},\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
that it is just a relaxation dynamics formulation of the original stationary Euler-Lagrange equations. I hope that, as $t$ goes to $\infty$, the  solution to this gradient descent dynamics converges  to the original solution of the Euler-Lagrange equation. However,

- in the formulation \eqref{1} above, the solution diverges for the obvious reason that $-u^2$ is downward concave respect to $u$.
- If change the formulation of the problem by putting a minus sign in front of the Lagrangian $L$ I get
  $$
  \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=-\frac{\delta{L}}{\delta{u}}=-2u-2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}.\label{2}\tag{2}
  $$ Unfortunately the term $-2u_{xx}$ makes the gradient descent solution unstable.

Therefore it arises my **question**: do there exists a relaxation dynamics problem formulation of the former minimization functional, alternative respect to \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} and suited for my purpose?

Comment: @daniele thx for your edits

Answer (score 4):

The usual way to ensure the convergence of the steepest descent formulation of the Euler-Lagrange equations, is to introduce a friction term, see [The Calculus of Variations](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~jwcalder/CalculusOfVariations.pdf) by Jeff Calder. Instead of
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=-\frac{\delta{L}}{\delta{u}}$$
you then have
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}+a\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=-\frac{\delta{L}}{\delta{u}}$$
with $a$ the friction coefficient.

Comment: many thanks Prof Beenakker. The Calculus of Variations by Jeff Calder is really great, but I don't think it talks about the case of adding $u_{tt}$ when the potential energy is non convex. Rather, they add $u_{tt}$ to accelerate the gradient descent numerics. I wonder if your approach of resolving my question is a well known one already or if there's any reference?

Comment: or is it true that this can't be resolved when there's only a 1st order time derivative?